# If statement combined with random row names

Tags: r

It seems to be a trivial question but i could not find out how to solve it.
Based on rownames of `DF` i need to fill the column. If `rowname=1`, column `a=i`, otherwise do not fill with anything.

```
DF
   a
2  
4
1
4
```

I have tried `if` statement and `DF[rownames(DF)==1]<-i`, that did nothing. Thank you for any suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `ifelse`

```
DF$Col2 <- ifelse(row.names(DF)==1, "i", "")
```

Comment: How you say here to put `i` into `a` column only?

Comment: @HoHoHo  Here, I am creating a column "Col2", Change it to `DF$a <-`